# How to request POST PUT methods with Celery and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am getting this error when I run this code: 
  NameError: name 'request' is not defined

This is my code

```
from app import app
from app import celery


@app.route("/name_async", methods=["POST"])
def name_call_async():
    name.delay()
    return 'async request'

@celery.task(name='run.name')
def name():
    a = request.form.get('NAME')
    return a
```

Comment: Of course request is not defined as you didn't import it! You need a `from flask import request`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't import `request`

`from flask import request`